MapProxy: The requested tile is outside the bounding box of the tile map
Some context:
I have a Map Proxy server with the following configuration:
services:
  demo:
  tms:
    use_grid_names: true

layers:
  - name: my_layer
    title: My example layer
    sources: [my_cache]

caches:
  my_cache:
    grids: [my_grid]
    disable_storage: true
    sources: [my_source]
    format: image/jpg

sources:
  my_source:
    type: tile
    url: https://example_tile_url/%(z)s/%(x)s/%(y)s.jpg
    grid: my_grid

grids:
  my_grid:
    srs: 'EPSG:XXXX' # My example SRS
    bbox: [four numbers representing the SRS' bbox here ("wgs84 bounds" by the EPSG website)]
    bbox_srs: 'EPSG:4326'
    origin: sw # Might be wrong, did not check properly
    res: [1000,9000,8000...] # Contains 13 values representing m/px
    tile_size: [256,256]
    num_levels: 12

globals:
  image:
    formats:
      image/jpg:
        encoding_options:
          jpeg_quality: 100 # (max quality)

When I manually insert a generated tile url, for example

http://ip:port/tms/my_layer/my_grid/5/1882/1660.jpg

in my web browser, I get the following error:
<TileMapServerError>
<Message>The requested tile is outside the bounding box of the tile map.</Message>
</TileMapServerError>

I've inserted zoom, row and column values that work perfectly fine, are within the EPSG:XXXX bounds im using, and are supposed to get a tile. but something within my configuration interprets these values as outside these defined bounds, which I got directly from the EPSG website, under the "WGS84 Bounds" section.
I have a slight suspicion that this is because of the grid's origin, but I've tried using all four available options and got the same result in all of them. I also found no way of specifying an origin point, like you can do in Proj4Leaflet
Perhaps it has something to do with MapProxy's default EPSG:XXXX configuration? because I have a slightly more customized Proj4 definition (in the same CRS of course) that works fine in my Proj4Leaflet web app.
Will hugely appreciate any assistance I could get on the matter ;)
